# Create table using d3.js

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I'm trying to create a html table from csv using d3.js
Here is my code:

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript"charset="utf-8">
            d3.text("team.csv", function(data) {
                var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(data);

                var container = d3.select("body")
                    .append("table")

                    .selectAll("tr")
                        .data(parsedCSV).enter()
                        .append("tr")

                    .selectAll("td")
                        .data(function(d) { return d; }).enter()
                        .append("td")
                        .text(function(d) { return d; });
            });
        </script>
```

It successfully reads all the records from the file but I just want to read first 5 rows. I'm just not sure how to add filter for this while using d3.

Looking Forward to some help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(data).slice(0,5) should work?

Comment: @ethan, That Worked!! Thanks a lot man, I never new this was just a matter of adding a simple slice function. Thanks again.